# Runtime warning when importing libraries in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, jupyter-notebook

So, I have never had this issue before on prior laptops- but recently on my new laptop- I get runtime warnings when trying to import libraries into Jupyter notebook- I'm not sure of the cause or how to fix it. Any solutions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qWJd.png)

Comment: Did you change any of the core files? If not, you can use conda to resintall numpy again and then check if the issue is still persisting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some problem with the package which showing warning. Try to re-install the package.

First check whether the package working properly. If not install the pakage. Here in your screenshot it shows problem with numpy. To install numpy follow

```
pip install numpy
```

Or

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

If the packages are working but still warning persist, then put the below code to remove the warning.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```